# C fputc error handling?

Tags: c, file, error-handling

Most C file writing examples for fputc use a very basic example with little or no error checking of the process.

What error-checking techniques and functions should I use in conjunction with a fputc loop to ensure that fputc has successfully written to file? And how should I use them?

The reason I ask for fputc specifically is I am working with a doubly-linked list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Checking the return value of `fputc` will usually not tell you anything useful, and will make your code hideous. The reason the return value of rarely meaningful is because stdio files are **buffered**, and a write error (usually due to exhausting disk space, but it could also be due to hardware failure which there's really no way to handle gracefully) will not be reported until the buffer is flushed. Because of this, it's also impossible to know, even when an error is reported, how much was successfully committed to disk.

As such, my view is that you should only use stdio to write files when you're willing to consider the entire "save" operation a failure if any error occurs during writing. If you take this approach, you can completely ignore the return value of all write functions. This is because the stdio `FILE` keeps an internal error indicator accessible as `ferror(f)`. So just do all your writes without checking for any errors, then before you close the file, check `ferror(f)`. If it returns a nonzero value, you know your "save" operation failed, and you can report this to the user and `remove` the partially-written file. Keep in mind you should be writing first to a temporary file then `rename` this into place, rather than writing directly over top of your old file, unless you want to risk destroying the user's old data on failure.

Comment: I am willing to consider any error during write operation as a total failure (given this is how I write my functions). Would you be willing to give example code of the ferror and temp file removal/renaming process?

Comment: I will comment that, when buffering reaches capacity it fflushes which might occur during the fputc loop. Without checking fputc there's no way to terminate prematurely (so it might continue to attempt to write a large gigabyte file for example that isn't writing to anything).

Comment: This is true. You could periodically check `ferror`, but there's no need to check after each byte; that will just make things slow and make your code cluttered. You could for example check after each whole line/record/etc. As for best practices for saving a file using temp files and renaming, I think you'll get some good advice if you post that as a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

You should check the `int` return value from `fputc()`. The [following is a list](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/fputc.3.asp):

> On success, fputc() returns the value c that it wrote to stream. On
>   failure, it returns EOF and sets errno to one of the following values:
>
> EACCES
>
> ```
> Another process has the file locked.
> ```
>
> EBADF
>
> ```
> stream is not a valid stream opened for writing.
> ```
>
> EFBIG
>
> ```
> The file is a regular file and an attempt was made to write at or
> ```
>
> beyond the offset maximum.
>
> EINTR
>
> ```
> A signal interrupted the call.
> ```
>
> EIO
>
> ```
> An output error occurred.
> ```
>
> ENOMEM
>
> ```
> Memory could not be allocated for internal buffers.
> ```
>
> ENOSPC
>
> ```
> An attempt is made to write to a full disk.
> ```
>
> ENXIO
>
> ```
> A device error occurred.
> ```
>
> EPIPE
>
> ```
> An attempt is made to write to a closed pipe.
> ```

Comment: So basically: if(fputc(C) != C){ perror("Error Occurred: "); clearerr(); return 1; }?