# fprintf failing, but fputc works just fine?

Tags: c, sockets, httpserver

I am trying to write a function that reads a line of text over a socket (it's part of the code I am writing for an HTTP Server for homework).

It works just fine writing to a file when I am writing using `fputc`.  However, when I try and copy the characters to a buffer, and then use `fprintf` to print the whole buffer to the file, I don't seem to be getting any output.

Here's the code:

```
int read_line(int fd, char *buffer, int size) {
    char *broken_buffer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * 8096);
    char next = '\0';
    char err;
    int i = 0;
    FILE *f = fopen("read_line2.txt", "w");
    while (i < size - 1 && next != '\n') {
        err = read(fd, &next, 1);
        if (err > 0) {
            if (next == '\r') {
                err = recv(fd, &next, 1, MSG_PEEK);
                if (err > 0 && next == '\n') {
                    read(fd, &next, 1);
                } else {
                    next = '\n';
                }
            }
            fputc(next, f); // Works
            broken_buffer[i] = next;
            buffer[i] = next;
            i++;
        } else {
            next = '\n';
        }
    }
    broken_buffer[i] = '\0';
    buffer[i] = '\0';
    FILE *out = fopen("read_line.txt", "w");
    fprintf(out, "%s\n", broken_buffer); // Does not work
    fclose(out);
    fclose(f);

    return i;
}
```

EDIT: I have tried using this alternative function:

```
int read_socket(int fd, char *buffer, int size) {
    int bytes_recvd = 0;
    int retries = 0;
    int total_recvd = 0;

    while (retries < MAX_RETRIES && size > 0 && strstr(buffer, ">") == NULL) {
        bytes_recvd = read(fd, buffer, size);

        if (bytes_recvd > 0) {
            buffer += bytes_recvd;
            size -= bytes_recvd;
            total_recvd += bytes_recvd;
        } else {
            retries++;
        }
    }

    if (bytes_recvd >= 0) {
        // Last read was not an error, return how many bytes were recvd
        return total_recvd;
    }
    // Last read was an error, return error code
    return -1;
}
```

And I have no problems printing this one out with fprintf.

EDIT2: I have figured out that `i` is somehow 0 after the loop, so the first character is being overwritten with a '\0'.  However, when I put in debugging code to print out the value of i within the loop, I found it being incremented up to 22 (23 being the final value at which the loop breaks).  How is this even possible?  The resulting string is:

```
GET /blah.txt HTTP/1.1
```

Comment: Are your sockets blocking or non-blocking? If it's blocking and there's nothing more to receive in the `read` call, it will block.

Comment: Oh, and you have a memory leak. You don't need to allocate the `broken_buffer` on the heap, just declare a normal array.

Comment: Also remember that opening a file with `"w"` _overwrites_ that file, so the next time you call `read_line` that file will be overwritten, meaning it will only contain the _last_ line read (which might be an empty line).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I think they're blocking, but I already know there's more data.

Comment: I also recommend you run this in a debugger, and step through line by line.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg This is all just for debugging, the calling function is actually the one I found the problem with.

Comment: Well, it seems you need to debug your debugging code. :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I guess so, I just don't know how to use gdb on C code when the code is actually being run in a child process...

Comment: Maybe because fputc uses buffers? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7462547

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be two processes that were both connecting to the server (thanks, Google Chrome...), and both were writing to the same file somehow.  The code WAS working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Is the value of `next` ever 0?  If it is 0 then that value will go into `broken_buffer`, which means that `fprintf` will think it's at the end of a string before you explicitly put the null there yourself.

Comment: I tried adding a check to compare `next` with `'\0'`, and there appears to be no difference.  I have used an alternative function (I edited this into the main post), which prints to a file correctly with fprintf.  It's very strange.